# [CloudFirestore]Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "firebase/app". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Im relatively new to firebase, and have a web app working but looking to connect a database.

Im just trying to pull a username and password just for testing purposes, but I get this error on pageload :

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "firebase/app". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

This is my code right now :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Welcome to Firebase Hosting</title>

  <!-- Firebase SDK scripts -->
  <script src="/__/firebase/10.4.0/firebase-app-compat.js"></script>
  <script src="/__/firebase/10.4.0/firebase-auth-compat.js"></script>
  <script src="/__/firebase/10.4.0/firebase-firestore-compat.js"></script>
  <!-- Include your other Firebase feature scripts here as needed -->
  <script defer src="/__/firebase/10.4.0/firebase-auth-compat.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/10.4.0/firebase-database-compat.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/10.4.0/firebase-firestore-compat.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/10.4.0/firebase-functions-compat.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/10.4.0/firebase-messaging-compat.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/10.4.0/firebase-storage-compat.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/10.4.0/firebase-analytics-compat.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/10.4.0/firebase-remote-config-compat.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/10.4.0/firebase-performance-compat.js"></script>

    <style media="screen">
      body {
        background: #ECEFF1;
        color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
        font-family: Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
  
      #message {
        background: white;
        max-width: 360px;
        margin: 100px auto 16px;
        padding: 32px 24px;
        border-radius: 3px;
      }
  
      #message h2 {
        color: #ffa100;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin: 0 0 8px;
      }
  
      #message h1 {
        font-size: 22px;
        font-weight: 300;
        color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
        margin: 0 0 16px;
      }
  
      #message p {
        line-height: 140%;
        margin: 16px 0 24px;
        font-size: 14px;
      }
  
      #message a {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        background: #039be5;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 16px;
        border-radius: 4px;
      }
  
      #message,
      #message a {
        box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
      }
  
      #load {
        color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 13px;
      }
  
      @media (max-width: 600px) {
  
        body,
        #message {
          margin-top: 0;
          background: white;
          box-shadow: none;
        }
  
        body {
          border-top: 16px solid #ffa100;
        }
      }
    </style>
  
    <script type="module">
      // Import Firebase modules properly
      import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
      import { getFirestore, doc, setDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';

    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "AIzaSyCtxBYLQ84DxSjQMGvksQvg7M2iCaBQ6g0",
      authDomain: "bsc-project-2-bf69a.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://bsc-project-2-bf69a-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app",
      projectId: "bsc-project-2-bf69a",
      storageBucket: "bsc-project-2-bf69a.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "707357656239",
      appId: "1:707357656239:web:d36ff2687cb3dafc7bc05a",
      measurementId: "G-L51G2JCM55"
    };

    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const db = getFirestore(app);

    async function storeInputData() {
      var username = document.getElementById("user").value;
      var password = document.getElementById("pass").value;

      console.log("Username: " + username);
      console.log("Password: " + password);

      const userRef = doc(db, "Users", username);

      try {
        await setDoc(userRef, {
          user: username,
          pass: password
        });
        console.log("Data Added, Success!");
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error adding data to Firestore: ", error);
      }
    }

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      const loadEl = document.querySelector('#load');

      try {
        let app = firebase.app();
        let features = [
          'auth',
          'database',
          'firestore',
          'functions',
          'messaging',
          'storage',
          'analytics',
          'remoteConfig',
          'performance',
        ].filter(feature => typeof app[feature] === 'function');
        loadEl.textContent = `Firebase SDK loaded with ${features.join(', ')}`;
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        loadEl.textContent = 'Error loading the Firebase SDK, check the console.';
      }
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <h1> WELCOME TO FCOT MEDIA </h1>
  </div>
  <div id="message">
    <h2>Welcome</h2>
    <h1>Firebase Hosting Setup Complete</h1>
    <p>You're seeing this because you've successfully set up Firebase Hosting. Now it's time to go build something extraordinary!</p>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/">Open Hosting Documentation</a>
  </div>
  <p id="load">Firebase SDK Loading&hellip;</p>

  <form id="userForm">
    <label for="user">Username: </label><input type="text" id="user" required><br><br>
    <label for="pass">Password: </label><input type="password" id="pass" required><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Create User">
  </form>

  <script> 
    function storeInputData(){
      var username = document.getElementById("user").value;
      var password = document.getElementById("pass").value;

      console.log("Username: " + username);
      console.log("Password: " + password);

      const userRef = doc(db, "Users", username)
      setDoc(userRef, {

        user:username,
        pass:password

      })
      

      .then (() => { 
        
        console.log("Data Added, Success!");

      })

      .catch ((error) => { 
        
        console.log("Womp Womp..", error);

      })

      document.getElementById("userForm").addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from submitting normally
        storeInputData(); // Call your function to store data
      });

    }

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Honestly, just tried that code.